# Provide social media button facility to mvc 4 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on MVC 4 application, I want to add social media buttons to my application. Basically i want to add facebook,twitter and pinterest buttons. When i click to facebook button, image need to post on postbook where i can have share option. after clicking to share button on facebook image need to share on facebook account. By clicking to shared facebook image on facebook account need to redirect particular url. Do we have such kind of provision available for MVC 4 or javascript.Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292139/Adding-Social-Buttons-Twitter-facebook-Google-plus) might help for the first step.

Comment: Thanks, but this will not fruitful to me.Please suggest alternate approach if any.

Comment: Hi Team,
I want to delete this question from Stack Overflow. Please help me to show step to delete permanently from Stack Overflow.

Comment: check [this] (https://www.google.ae/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwi1-cOn94LJAhWJ7BQKHVTnCkY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F42265%2Fhow-can-i-delete-my-question&usg=AFQjCNHK86LcAoy23LrkOvvygOVJljrpVQ&sig2=brIlKqc5m_tkHzuNJYpLiw&bvm=bv.106923889,d.d24)

Answer (score 0):

All social websites have some JavaScript library. So basically you can include the JS library to your project and generate your own HTML code with data atributes. The same way I use on my own blog: https://www.miroslavholec.cz/blog

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet" data-url="YOUR-URL"></a>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="YOUR-URL" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
```

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button
- https://about.twitter.com/cs/resources/buttons#tweet
- https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/

Comment: Hi, I did not find fruitful code which can help me out.Can you provide some code based on my query that will be great help ? Please suggest some code on it.Thanks